# I want to make a div inside of my movable div that acts like a window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a `div` inside of my movable `div` that acts like a window that can hold content and carries the same width as the draggable `div`. Exactly like a program on your computer works/looks like (the bar at the top is draggable but if you tried to drag the content in the app it wouldn't work).

Here's my code so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }

        #divcontainer {
            border: 1px solid lightgray;
            width: 100%
            height: 100%

        }

        #makeitmove {
            background: lightgray;
            resize: both;
            overflow: auto;
            text-align: center;
            width: 500px;
            height: 76px;
            border: 1px solid grey;
            cursor: move;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#makeitmove").draggable({containment: "#divcontainer", scroll: false});
        });
    </script>
    <div id="window" style="display: none;"></div>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="divcontainer" style="height: 100vh;">
        <div id="makeitmove">Calculator
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And is it OK if you also disabled the scrollbars on the main page for me (but not for the window), not quite sure how to do that? Thanks a lot in advance for the help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use handle option of draggable to specify a place where you want dragging enabled.

for more information https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#handle

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }

        #divcontainer {
            border: 1px solid lightgray;
            width: 100%
            height: 100%

        }

        #makeitmove {
            background: lightgray;
            resize: both;
            overflow: auto;
            text-align: center;
            width: 500px;
            height: 76px;
            border: 1px solid grey;
        }

        #drag {
            height: 20px;
            width: 100%;
            background: blue;
        }

    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#makeitmove").draggable({containment: "#divcontainer", handle: '#drag', scroll: false});
        });
    </script>
    <div id="window" style="display: none;"></div>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="divcontainer" style="height: 100vh;">
        <div id="makeitmove">
            <div id="drag"></div>
            Calculator
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for making the resizing work too! Thats super helpful :))

Comment: do you know how I could make it only resizable within the div container and it cannot go out of those borders when being resized and also resizable from all edges and corners?

Comment: You can use https://jqueryui.com/resizable/#constrain-area to keep it inside container. and http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-handles to resize from all edges. I created an example for it here http://jsfiddle.net/chobann/7ok4v26g/

Answer (score 1):

### Edited...

There you go!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
html, body{
height:100%;
margin:0;
}

#divcontainer{
border: 1px solid lightgray;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
#makeitmove{
background: white;
resize: both;
overflow: auto;
text-align: center;
width: 500px;
height: 76px;
border: 1px solid grey;
}
#handle {
background: lightgray;
height: 20px;
cursor: move;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#makeitmove").draggable( {containment: "#divcontainer", handle: "#handle", scroll: false} );
});
</script>
<div id="window" style="display: none;"></div>
</head>
<body>
<div id="divcontainer" style="height: 100vh;">
<div id="makeitmove">
    <div id="handle"></div>
    <span>Calculator</span>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this works visually but is draggable everywhere which wasn't really what I was aiming for, @Clujio was spot on though! Thanks for both of you guys' help! :)

Comment: Ah, OK. I missed that part. However, you need to add box-sizing: content-box; to remove the vertical scrollbar, for you have 1px border width and that kinda screw the entire height control a little bit.